# How to remove xla from xls without renaming or deleting xla file?

Tags: excel, vba, xls, xla

I need to get rid of an XLA (excel add-in) from a spreadsheet, but everything on the web seems to point to renaming/deleting the xla file.

This is not an option as the xla file is used by many other spreadsheets and is on a shared drive.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Struggling to understand this one a bit.  An XLA is not "in" any one spreadsheet, it *is* a spreadsheet, albeit one that is loaded into the Excel executable in a different way.  This means you can't remove it from another spreadsheet.

What are you trying to remove this XLA from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied all the classes and modules (drag and drop) from the xla to the 'local' project.

Save and close xls

I searched for the xla project name in the registry (with excel closed) and deleted the value.

Open excel

Done

Answer (score 2):

Move or rename the .xla file, then go to add-in manager. select the add-in, and click "delete" on the pop-up massage.

Comment: You cannot do this as it is in use by other spreadsheets (as I stated in the original post)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to remove it from the add-in dialog box?  Disconnect from the shared drive, load Excel, and try to install the add-in.  Excel will tell you it can't find it and ask if you want to remove it.  Once you've removed it, reconnect to the shared drive.

Comment: It appears to be referenced as \\server\folder\thing.xla, so I doubt I can disconnect as such

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the solution might be:

1. On the Tools menu, click Add-Ins.
2. In the Add-Ins available box, clear the check box next to the add-in you want to unload, and then click OK.

Source: **http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052037321033.aspx**

Comment: Having to retype comment coz the site went down grrr...

It doesn't work.
It still shows up in the IDE

Comment: @Martin:Can we do the steps u have mentioned programatically using c#?if yes then how?

Comment: @Smack: Why would you do that from c# ?

Comment: I developed the template project(.xlt) which require the paste special mtd to paste only values.It is difficult to trap the ctrl+v event with c# so i have developed the addin which does the paste special for me..I want to uninstall the addin i.e.(.xla) file when user uninstalls the template so that user will not prompted with File removed Alert everytime when user opens excel...

Comment: I'm not sure if it is doable, but you could ask a new question on stackoverflow. This has not much to do with this actual question.